# Kibana showing too many buckets exception. How to increase the buckets or is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, bucket

What is the exact use of bucket size in Kibana ?

```
 [esaggs] > Request to Elasticsearch failed: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"too_many_buckets_exception","reason":"Trying to create too many buckets. Must be less than or equal to: [10000] but was [10001]. This limit can be set by changing the [search.max_buckets] cluster level
```

I am getting this error, I am dealing with 10000+ documents, do I need to expand the bucket size ?
Currently I am using the bucket size as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [ES official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-settings.html#search-settings-max-buckets),

> search.max_buckets (Dynamic, integer) Maximum number of aggregation
> buckets allowed in a single response. Defaults to 10000.
>
> Requests that attempt to return more than this limit will return an
> error.

`max_buckets` setting is available at the cluster level settings, you can change it using the below command (but it may adversely affect your cluster)

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient": {
    "search.max_buckets": 20000
  }
}
```

**Refer to this [discuss post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/increasing-max-buckets-for-specific-visualizations/187390), to know more about this.**